# Crystal Reports: get access to linked elements in selection formula

Tags: crystal-reports, report, formula, crystal-reports-2008

I'm making a report using Crystal Reports 2008 and Peachtree database. Report should display customers who didn't place orders in a last 30 days. I already figured out how to link two tables in CR with left outer join. But I wasn't able to find how that linking can be used in formulas, such as selection formula. What I am trying to achieve is to get date of last placed order for current customer and use this information to determine if customer should be displayed or not.
What is the right approach to solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is setup properly and adding 'customer' and 'last order date' to the details section shows you everything, then you can just add conditional formatting formula for the suppress property of the section when 'data date - last order date < 30', leaving you only showing records where last order date is more than 30 days.